# How does Hybris salt its MD5 password hashes?

Tags: sap-commerce-cloud

Hybris (version 5.1) can store user passwords in the clear (the default), or using MD5. The MD5 option is not a straight MD5 hash of the password, so i suspect some kind of "salting" is involved. But what? My goal is to be able to write a password reset application that can write new random passwords to the hybris database in MD5 mode (not in the clear).

---

Getting a little closer: I know that my configuration is using core.saltedMD5PasswordEncoder, and that the value of the salt is set in hybris/bin/platform/ext/core/resources/core-spring.xml

Still, without the source for saltedMD5PasswordEncoder, i may not get very far.

Answer (score 2):

Hybris supports more than one password encoding schema. Which schema or strategy is actually used depends on your configuration.
You will have to look up the documentation for your password encoding strategy to see how the fields are mapped.

Usually a salt is randomly generated for each user and stored together with the password in the same object (database row).

Furthermore MD5 should not be used anymore. It is broken beyond repair and a salt will not fix it.

Please consult the hybris documentation on password encoding https://wiki.hybris.com/display/release5/Password+Storage+Strategies
and stack overflow for password storage best practices.

Comment: I should have mentioned that we are on version 5.1 Looks like things changed between 5.1 and the version in this documentation (5.7). On 5.1, the default is plain text and the only other option is MD5.

Comment: The answer to your question is "it depends on your configuration". As @wdick says, have a look at the documentation. If you have left everything as default, changed nothing and gone live, then I pity the guy you are charging.